# MLE for Cobb Douglas function

Tags: r

I have tried to estimate MLE for cobb douglas production function. I have created my log function:

```
myDD<-function(alpha,gamma,delta,sigma,theta){
+ n<-NROW(lk)
+ e<-ly+theta*yy-log(gamma)-alpha*(1-delta)*lk-alpha*delta*ll
+ DD<-((-n/2)*log(2*pi))-((n/2)*log(sigma))-((t(e)%*%e)/(2*sigma))
+ return(-DD)
+ }
```

and tried to run a command:

```
myMLE<-mle2(myDD,start = list(alpha=1,gamma=1,delta=1,sigma=1,theta=0.001))
```

but it said me that lk not found. I cannot understand why and where I have to specify lk.

Comment: Can you call `myDD` outside `mle2` without errors?

Comment: did not understand what you wanted to ask?

Comment: Does `myDD` work correcty if you call it directly?

Comment: when i run myDD or run View(myDD) command it gives me these results:                                                  function(alpha,gamma,delta,sigma,theta){
n<-NROW(lk)
e<-ly+theta*yy-log(gamma)-alpha*(1-delta)*lk-alpha*delta*ll
DD<-((-n/2)*log(2*pi))-((n/2)*log(sigma))-((t(e)%*%e)/(2*sigma))
return(-DD)
}

Comment: You did not call the function! 
Try
 `> MyDD(alpha=0.5,gamma=0.5,delta=0.5,sigma=0.5,theta=0.5)`